# iOS 6 app redeem

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I know this isn't programming question, but I am out of options.
I've published new version of the app to the app store, v1.1.1, and it redeems successfully on iOS 8. But when I try to redeem it with iPhone 4 iOS 6, app store downloads previous version, v1.1.0.

It's currently waiting for the manual release and I wanted to test it on iOS 6 as well. It builds normally through Xcode on iOS 6, and installs with Enterprise build.

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell more. First of all you can not upload binary with enterprise account. For uploading binary on iTunes store you have to sign it with production certificate.

v1.1.1 - status on iTunes store ?
v1.1.0 - status on iTunes store ?

What is the minimum sdk for both these version ?

Comment: I did not upload the enterprise binary to iTunes Connect. I tested it locally.
v1.1.1 is pending release on iTunes Connect.
v1.1.0 is live on app store.
Minimum SDK is 6.1, testing with iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: So it's clear dude, v1.1.1 is pending release that means prior version is live on store.

Comment: you said "But when I try to redeem it with iPhone 4 iOS 6, app store downloads previous version, v1.1.0" - On app store you have v.1.1.0 Live not 1.1.1 as it's pending for release.

Comment: Redeeming on iOS 7 and 8 downloads v1.1.1

Comment: Make sure device you are using. I guess you have added your iOS 7 and 8 device as internal/external tester so those device are getting pending for release version. Otherwise this is not possible. If you download from app store you will only get Live version only.

Comment: It is possible to download, through redeem code if the application is pending release. I am not testing via Testflight.